# Unity 5 64bit Facebook 6.2.1 plugin problems

Tags: facebook, plugins, unity-game-engine

I updated to the Latest Unity 5 and now I have some issues with the latest Facebook plugin 6.2.1 and Webplayer.

All seems to work ok except when I use this:

```
        FB.AppRequest(
        message: "my message", 
        callback: FacebookInvitesCallback
        );
```

nothing happens, no error message, nothing..
It doesnt open a friends window, nothing.
This works in the Editor, it opens a friends window.
It doesnt even go to

```
void FacebookInvitesCallback(FBResult response) {Debug.Log("I am here");}
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake. Facebook SDK for Unity only supports Unity 4. See the note at the top.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads

Comment: Does anyone know where to find a timeline/schedule when FB Unity SDK will start supporting Unity 5? Or are we expected to opt for iOS SDk and Android SDK once we port to Unity 5?